# Use Postcss in Custom Angular Library

Tags: angular, webpack, postcss, rollupjs, ng-packagr

I used [postcss](https://postcss.org/), [postcss-css-modules](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules) and [posthtml-css-modules](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-css-modules) to implement CSS Modules in a Angular Application. I also used [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/7.x.x/packages/custom-webpack/README.md) to achieved this.

Now, I want to do the same with my Custom Angular Library. However, I cannot use [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/7.x.x/packages/custom-webpack/README.md) because the Angular Libraries are build using [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr).

So, [@angular-builders/custom-webpack](https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/blob/7.x.x/packages/custom-webpack/README.md) is not available to use: https://github.com/just-jeb/angular-builders/issues/356

On the other hand, [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr) does not support [postcss](https://postcss.org/): https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/1471

I have read that it's possible to extend [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) config (is the compiler that use [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr) at the end of the build) in [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr):

https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/DESIGN.md#rollup-config

But I didn't find any documentation to achieve this.

Does anybody know how to do it?

Other solution that I thought, it's make all the styles global and compile them using [scss-bundle](https://github.com/reactway/scss-bundle) and postcss like I did here: [NodeJs Script that compiles scss files fails because of postcss rule for undefined variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60712566/nodejs-script-that-compiles-scss-files-fails-because-of-postcss-rule-for-undefin)

And after If I can use [lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash) I will be able to replace the class names by their hashed class name like is proposed here: [Use [hash:base64:5] in JavaScript / TypeScript file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60512235/use-hashbase645-in-javascript-typescript-file)

But to do that, I will need to know how to invoke lodash in the build of [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr).

Does anybody knows how to do that?

Any other solution is more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ng-packagr is already using postcss.  https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/src/lib/styles/stylesheet-processor.ts. What is you want to achieve?

Comment: Hi @GouravGarg , Thanks for your answer.
I want to use postcss-css-modules and  posthtml-css-modules in the build of my Angular Library. 
Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: I was able to use postcss-css-modules and posthtml-css-modules in a Angular Project and it was possible thanks to @angular-builders/custom-webpack . However, I can't use @angular-builders/custom-webpack  in the build of a Angular Library, because of that I do not how to use  postcss-css-modules and posthtml-css-modules in the build of a Custom Angular Library.

Comment: May be this can help you a bit https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/643

Comment: Yes, that is a good help. It seems to be the branch has not been merged yet.
Do you have another idea? Or Is it possible to use that version that has not been merged yet? Thanks in advance.

Comment: until then you can pre-process those styles with postcss and then pass to your library. This can help you a little https://medium.com/@Dor3nz/compiling-css-in-new-angular-6-libraries-26f80274d8e5

Comment: Yes, that is useful. But, I also need to do some changes in the html of the components. I can use lodash for that, the problem is I do not know how, because the HTML are embedded after the build.
Do you know how to achieve that?
Does exist any compiler like scss-bundle for the html's?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can handle that in postbuild process

Comment: Is it possible to modify the HTML embedded in the bundles/dist files?
How can I do that?

Comment: its easy to rename files and do simple things. complexity depends on what you want to achieve. Also, you are saying that HTML are embedded after the build.

Comment: In my case, I want to take all class names in HTML files and change the class name by a value in a json file. Example, before change: ```<div class="container">``` after change  ```<div class="_.asdasd">``` , the value ```"_.asdasd"``` is going to be in a json file like this: ```{ "container" : "_.asdasd" }```

Comment: There are a couple of webpack tools which you can use after this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45644590/webpack-plugin-to-modify-files-after-compilation  https://www.npmjs.com/package/replace-in-file-webpack-plugin

Comment: Awesome, however, those tools are to use with webpack. I am not using webpack as compiler.
Can I use them as js or typescprit script after the build?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211068/discussion-between-gourav-garg-and-german-quinteros).

Comment: this is working or what?

Comment: When I searched for this today I found https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-packagr-rollup-postcss which seems not working and like an unfinished or abandoned work. It's seems a published version of this fork https://github.com/SmallShrimp/ng-packagr-postcssrollup which I couldn't find any specific commit related to fixing that, although after installing the npm package it has a rollup folder which is not working and after some hacking, I end up with some errors so I thought it is not a completed effort if anyone can figure out how to use it (if usable) please share here as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a discussion going on this enhancement. May be changes are still in progress. You can track from [here](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/issues/643)

You can pre-process your styles and then pass to ng-packagr as suggested by this [article](https://medium.com/@Dor3nz/compiling-css-in-new-angular-6-libraries-26f80274d8e5)

Other problem to embed with HTML files you can use create a post build process something like [this](https://github.com/alan-agius4/ng-mono-repo-starter/blob/master/tools/tasks/build.ts) with help of these [tools](https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules#integration-with-templates)

I hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem here is that https://github.com/css-modules/postcss-modules#integration-with-templates is executed during the build. After ng-packagr build the Angular Library all the templates (HTML) are embedded and I need to modify those templates. Do you have a idea to modify the templates during the build or after?

Comment: If this problem exist with all of the applications and these variables are same for all applications. You can update HTML files permanently, if that suits you.

Comment: That is not a suitable solution because if I do that I will replace the original class names by their hashed class names, and I need to keep the original class names.
I would like to replace the class names by their hashed class names during the build or after in the dist files.
Do you have any idea/solution for that case?