# ng-packagr extend rollup config

Tags: javascript, angular, postcss, rollupjs, ng-packagr

I have a Custom Angular Library and I would like to customize the build of that Library using [postcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss).

Like the Angular Libraries are built using [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr), I need to extend the `rollup.config.js` of [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr) to customize the build of my Library.

In fact, I would like to use [postcss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss) through [rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) like is used here:
https://www.learnwithjason.dev/blog/learn-rollup-css/

I saw in the documentation of [ng-packagr](https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr) that is possible to extend the rollup config:
https://github.com/ng-packagr/ng-packagr/blob/master/docs/DESIGN.md#rollup-config

However, I didn't find any documentation or example on how to do that.

Does anybody know how to do that?

Can anybody provide me an example?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add more information what you tried to achieve what you are looking for. Any demo that you have done. If any please share the details so that I can contribute. I didn't the full context what you are looking for here.

Comment: Hi @AnoopRajasekharaWarrier , thanks for your response.
I have just updated my question. Also, I have a more generic question that is related to this topic here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937107/use-postcss-in-custom-angular-library

Any help is more than welcome. Thanks !!!

Comment: I commented here which is your duplicate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60937107/use-postcss-in-custom-angular-library

Comment: Could you say if you found a solution?